# How to set canvas url for facebook application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, api, canvas

This question has been asked many times previously, but, recently the Facebook developers website has apparently changed and therefore, the solution isn't available anywhere.

Here's what the problem looks like:
[image]

**(Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.)**

Now, the following this the app settings page:
[image]

i.e, there's no option to set canvas url or secure canvas url. What should I do to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have this new dashboard UI yet but look under that "Add Platform" button for something along the lines of "App on Facebook"

Comment: That works! How the hell didn't I notice it?! Thanks

Comment: it is only asking for Secure (HTTPS) url. Can't we set http url ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You should add App on Facebook platform in your Settings tab.